# Spring boot pre api action annotation

Tags: validation, spring-boot, playframework

I'm new using Spring boot , but i come from a Play! framework background.

In Play there was something called action "Action Composition"

```
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaActionsComposition
```

It is used to do some code logic before going through the api method , so it could be used for creating a custom security for example or whatever logic we want to add before accessing an api method.

Then we simply annotate whatever api with this Action.

Is there something similar to do in Spring boot ?

I have googled for actions/ validators , but i did not find results similar to Play framework's action composition behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an `interceptor`. Its purpose is to allow some action to be taken before an actual API endpoint is reached.

This [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) should help.